# comparing and defining strings in C

Tags: c

I looked at other answers, but was not able to find an answer.
I want to compare the last character of a string to the literal "%".

```
  strcpy(ch, fName[strlen(fName) - 1]);
  printf("%d\n", strcmp(ch, "%"));
```

I want to compile with the cl command line compiler (MicroSoft), and get warnings:

```
cbx_test1.c(43) : warning C4047: 'function' : 'const char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'char'
cbx_test1.c(43) : warning C4024: 'strcpy' : different types for formal and actual parameter 2
```

There is something wrong with my code, that's obvious. But what?

Comment: What is `ch` and `fName`? How are those variables declared?

Comment: Don't use `strcmp()` to compare a single character. Use `ch == fname[i]` instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to consider that strings in c, are sequences of non-`nul` bytes followed by a `nul` byte, you are trying to copy a character with `strcpy()` which is meant to copy *strings*, so that's why your compiler is complaining.

You can do that by simple assignment, i.e.

```
char   ch;
size_t length;

length = strlen(fname);
ch     = fname[length - 1];
```

and then you can compare `ch` with the `'%'` character constant like this

```
printf("%d\n", (ch == '%'));
```

note the *single quotes*, what you wanted to do is possible though not necessary, like this

```
char   ch[2];
size_t length;

length = strlen(fname);

strcpy(ch, &fname[length - 1]);
printf("%d\n", strcmp(ch, "%"));
```

notice that **two** characters where allocated for the `"%"` to become a string since it requires the terminating `nul` byte, like `%\0`, you don't need to explicitly specify it when you use a string literal like `"%"` since it's implied.

You could also use `memcmp()` which is also not necessary in this case, but I think it's interesting to mention that `strcmp()` is not the only way to compare two strings in c, you could<sup>1</sup>

```
char   ch[1];
size_t length;

length = strlen(fname);
ch[0]  = fname[length - 1];

printf("%d\n", memcmp(ch, fname + length - 1, 1));
```

notice that in this case the terminating `'\0'` is not required because we are instructing `memcmpt()` to compare just 1 byte.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Note that `fname + length - 1` is equivalent to `&fname[length - 1]`</sub>

Comment: char   ch;
size_t length;

length = strlen(fname);
ch     = fname[length - 1];
and then you can compare ch with the '%' character constant like this

printf("%d\n", (ch == '%'));

This is a very useful answer!

Answer (score 7):

The issue in your case is, `fName[strlen(fName) - 1]` is of type `char`, not a `const char *`, as needed by [`strcpy()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy). Also, we don't know about the type of `ch` used here.

Considering `fName` is an array of type `char`, what you want here is

```
if ('%' == fName[strlen(fName)-1])
   //do something
```

Comment: @Abhi even though your [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7532788) got rejected, it was a valid one. Thanks, I've made the changes. :-)

Comment: I am curious - why did you reject it  then?

Comment: @Abhi If you see properly, it got rejected by community, not by me. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If `fName[]` , is a character array, then your code

```
strcpy(ch, fName[strlen(fName) - 1]);
```

is wrong, because, `strcpy()` expects a character array ( or in other words, a `const char *` ) as a parameter, not a single character.

If you just want to check a single character , then an if statement is more than enough, something like

```
if ( fName[strlen(fName) - 1] == '%' )
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in both lines.

> `strcpy(ch, fName[strlen(fName) - 1]);`

`strcpy` wants both params to be of `char *`. Buth both arguements are ch not the char *. Replace this statement with

```
ch = fName[strlen(fName) - 1];
```

> `printf("%d\n", strcmp(ch, "%"));`

I think in this line you wanted to see the result of strcmp to be `0`, which validates that ch equals to `'%'`. Following should work for you

```
if(fName[strlen(fName) - 1] == '%')
//do something
```

OR
using the code for first statement

```
if (ch == '%')
//Do something
```